# Math behind numpy.roots

Tags: python, numpy, math

What is the math behind [numpy.roots](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html)?
How does numpy find the roots of an equation?

Comment: [Source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.0/numpy/lib/polynomial.py#L148-L230)  link on docs page

Comment: Maybe this question should by on [Mathematics Stack Echange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), in a more general wording "How does one find the roots of an equation?" (but there's no simple general answer to that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link of the documentation that you provided ([numpy.roots](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html)) says that *the algorithm relies on computing the eigenvalues of the companion matrix*. The math is on the page 191 (3.3 The minimal polynomial and the companion matrix) of the book [Matrix analysis](http://www.cse.zju.edu.cn/eclass/attachments/2015-10/01-1446086008-145421.pdf).

Also, here's a pretty good explanation: [Eigenvalue-Polynomials](http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Spring17/Eigenvalue-Polynomials.pdf). This is more like an overview of the algorithm. It doesn't tell *how* to calculate the eigenvectors.

Hope that helps :)